# Scroll responsive content in overflow div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, overflow

I made a responsive overflow container with images and I want to put 2 buttons to make a animation slide left and right. The animation must stops to the last image for the right button and to the first image for the left button.

The website is fullscreen with header and footer 50px height and the middle content responsive.

Here is my code.

Stylesheet

```
html, body
{
    min-height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#wrapper
{
    padding:50px 0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}

#content
{
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow:scroll;
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:relative;
    /*overflow-y: hidden;*/
}

 header
{
    margin-top:-50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}

 footer
{
    margin-bottom:-50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}

 .imagg
{
    max-height:100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

  .container
{
    background:#FF0;
    position:absolute;
    width:100% !important;
    height:100% !important;
    max-height:100% !important;
}
```

and the html

```
<div id="wrapper">
<header></header>
<div id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="test.jpg" class="imagg" id="first" />
        <img src="test.jpg" class="imagg" />
        <img src="test.jpg" class="imagg" />
        <img src="test.jpg" class="imagg" />
        <img src="test.jpg" class="imagg" />
        <img src="test.jpg" class="imagg" />
        <img src="test.jpg" class="imagg" />
        <img src="test.jpg" class="imagg" id="last" />
    </div>
</div>
<button id="left">&laquo;</button>
<button id="right">&raquo;</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#right").click(function() {
    $( ".container" ).animate({ "left": "+=200px" }, "slow" );
});

    $("#left").click(function() {
    $( "#container" ).animate({ "right": "-=200px" }, "slow" );
});
</script>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var numOfSlide=3;
var navigation=numOfSlide;
$("#right").click(function() {     
    if(navigation<(numOfSlide+(numOfSlide-1))){
         $( ".container" ).animate({ "left": "+=200px" }, "slow" );
        navigation++;
    }  
});

$("#left").click(function() {
    if(navigation > (numOfSlide-(numOfSlide-1))){
         $( ".container" ).animate({ "left": "-=200px" }, "slow" );
        navigation--;
   }     
});
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fTnvE/

Comment: And if I want to start from the first image (left) and finish to the last image? With no white spaces on the right and left? So the right button stop when the last image show and the left when the first image